# Implementing a progress bar for downloading WEB-API responses

Tags: android

I am trying to create a download progress bar while i am downloading files. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/) however i can only make the progress bar count when i download files like images or mp3s.

What i need to be able to download are api responses such as [these](http://maps5.trimet.org/osm?mode=BICYCLE&toPlace=45.504966,-122.654349&fromPlace=45.5115225,-122.647633), but i cannot get their file size in order to have a reference for my progress bar.

```
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
```

When used on the API responses, the file size are -1 so the whole function is wrong.

What is a way to identify their sizes or any alternative way to create a progress bar while you download these.

Edit: I already am using Async task and it is working, the only problem is that i cannot increment my progress bar since i cannot get a file size.

Comment: you can use Async task.....

Comment: @PiyushGupta: sorry forgot to mention, i am using async task already. I just need to know how to identify the file size of the file i am downloading or a way to increment the count for my progress dialog.

Comment: you can refer this link..Useful to you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog